# How to get the look and feel of ios 6 on a device having ios 7 using xcode 5.1..?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

How to get the look and feel of ios 6 on a device having ios 7 using xcode 5.1..?

I have an app which is currently have the look and feel of ios 6 and does not have flat UI supported.
I was using xcode 4.6 and was deploying the app on ios 7 so the look and feel was of ios 6.

But now since I have moved to XCODE 5.1 the app when deployed on ios 7 gives the look and feel of ios 7.

Is there any way I can still make it look like the ios 6 UI.?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IOS8 just came out, you should download Xcode 6 and start developing for it since in a couple weeks I think more than 90% of the products will run it.

Comment: What? Why? iOS6 is now 2 versions out of date. You should really be updating your app to match the new look and feel.

Comment: @Fogmeister totally agree. However When iOS7 came out with the new look and feel my bosses wanted to stay with the old look and feel and try to get me to make our apps running on iOS7 look this way fortunately they saw sense and dropped this requirement. My point here though is it could be a business decision that the OP has no control over being made. Stupid I know but trying to convince the business that they are making stupid decision is harder then it sounds.

Comment: @Popeye ok, very true. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the look and feel of ios6 on ios7 devices, you need to add and use the images of ios6 resources.

Images for button background, Table background, etc. for each component which is used in your app.

We don't get ios6 resources in ios7 device by default.

Comment: As you are using Xcode 5.1, You can test your app on iOS6.1 simulator by downloading it.

But Xcode 6 does not offer/support iOS6.1 simulator download.